# In C++, is it meaningful to say that a variable has type rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

The way I think about something like `X&& x = static_cast<X&&>(obj_x);` is that, appearances notwithstanding, `x` ends up being an ordinary lvalue reference.  I've recently come across [this article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) where Scott Meyers insists that `x` would be an lvalue of type rvalue reference. Is this really meaningful, or is it a distinction without a difference?  Specifically, given either

```
X&& x = static_cast<X&&>(obj_x)
```

or

```
X& x = obj_x;
```

is there any subsequent code that will behave differently for these two definitions of `x`?

Comment: `decltype(x)`. If `x` is a non-static data member, it also affects the generation of copy constructor.

Comment: Why not turn this comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The important distinction is whether the R-value reference is named or unnamed (return value).

So, to answer the question as written, no, no **subsequent** code would treat the two definitions of x differently (except, as cpplearner mentions, `decltype()`). Only the definition of x would matter in what the reference can *bind to* (the fancy term that will help web searches).

Anything with a name can be referred to again, so it gets treated like an l-value for purposes of binding onto subsequent references. Why? Because the primary reason for r-value references is to enable something to be *moved from*. After you move from it, it's no longer viable. All you can do is destroy it or assign over it. Not a big deal if the thing doesn't have a name, but if it has a name, it's easy to accidentally use it again. That's why you need to call std::move(mything) to move out of mything [except in some return cases].

I think it was an article by Herb Sutter that made me get this detail, unfortunately I can't find it right now. If I'm misremembering, it might have been by Stephan T Lavavej.